# How to write the exact text next to the text and replace certain letters in it? SQLite

Tags: sqlite, replace, sql-update, db-browser-sqlite

I am creating a phonetic dictionary for American English. Here are some examples:

```
vocabulary      phonetic_transcription
dream           dɹim
drain           dɹeɪn
drink           dɹɪŋk
adrenaline      əˈdɹɛnəlɪn
```

If dɹ is in the phonetic_transcription, I want to write an alternative to it replacing 'd' with 'ʤ'. The expected outcome is:

```
vocabulary      phonetic_transcription
dream           dɹim / ʤɹim
drain           dɹeɪn / ʤɹeɪn
drink           dɹɪŋk / ʤɹɪŋk
adrenaline      əˈdɹɛnəlɪn / əˈʤɹɛnəlɪn
```

I know how to change a certain element with another with replace function but I have no idea how to do it like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string functions like `INSTR()` to filter the table so that only rows with `phonetic_transcription` that contain `'dɹ'` will be updated and `REPLACE()` to replace the string `'dɹ'` with `'ʤɹ'`:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET phonetic_transcription = phonetic_transcription || ' / ' || REPLACE(phonetic_transcription, 'dɹ', 'ʤɹ')
WHERE INSTR(phonetic_transcription, 'dɹ');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a06e62cb43042f3ce9a549f1274ab779).

Comment: As far as I understand, you changed a certain element (dɹ) with another (ʤɹ) but it is different from the expected outcome. 

the phonetic equivalent of the words should be -the original one / the version where dɹ is changed with ʤɹ- for example dream should be dɹim / ʤɹim not just ʤɹim. Sorry If I wasn't able to clearly convey what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Aschente I know, I have already edited after realizing what you asked for. Check my edited code.